# In which conditions a list turns into a string in python?

Tags: python

Hello guys I've got a little piece of code here that is giving me a headache. In this function I define a list called `word` and all of sudden the list becomes a string. I don't know how is this possible:

```
def find_best_shift(wordlist, text):
    words = []
    word = []
    for x in range(0, 27):
        apply_shift(text, x)
        for character in text:
            print (type(word))
            if (character in ALPHABET) or (character in alphabet):
                word.append(character)
            else:
                wor = ''.join(word)
                words.append(wor)
                word = []
        for word in words:
            y = is_word(wordlist, word)
            if y == True:
                return x
```

You guys notice the print statement `print(type(word))`. With this statement I get the following output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

And then it gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Python Projects\ps4\ps4.py", line 264, in    find_best_shift
word.append(character)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for word in words:
```

reassigns the same name (`word`) to be an element of the `words` list before moving on to the next value for `x`. Change this to something else.

```
for item in words:
```

Reusing names can cause some funny headaches :(

Don't forget to update

```
y = is_word(wordlist, word)
```

to

```
y = is_word(wordlist, item)
```

And I would simplify

```
if y == True:
```

To simply

```
if y:
```

Explicitly comparing to Boolean literals can cause some interesting results if you start chaining conditions together.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept when it lets you! And sorry about the somewhat random capitalization...iPhone is a terrible SO platform :-p

Comment: @user2644430 always forget to tag people in these comments... FYI iPhone won't autocomplete the names for these alerts :(